# Disable previous button if the tab is the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable the previous button if the tab is the first, and also disable Next button if the tab is the last. This is my script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tabs = $('.tabbable li');
    $('#prevtab').on('click', function () {
        $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    });
    $('#nexttab').on('click', function () {
        $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    });
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="tabbable">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab_bar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
          Some text here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
      Some text here
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="prevtab" type="button">Back</button>
  <button class="btn" id="nexttab" type="button">Next</button>
```

How can I disable the back and the next button if the tab is first/last?

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tabs = $('.tabbable li');

    $('#prevtab').attr("disabled", true);

    $('#prevtab').on('click', function () {

        if ($tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').length == 1) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
        $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        $('#nexttab').prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $('#nexttab').on('click', function () {
        if ($tabs.filter('.active').next('li').length == 1) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        }
        $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
        $('#prevtab').prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe like this

```
 $('#prevtab').on('click', function () {
    if($tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').length==0)
    { 
      $(this).attr("disabled",true);
     }
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');

});
```

**Edit**

```
$('#nexttab').on('click', function () {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    $('#prevtab').prop("disabled",false);
});
```

When will you click on the next button, it will get enable again

Comment: yes, that is the logic, but it becomes disabled after i click on it, and it stays disabled

Comment: what are the actions for the tabs? it's ok for the buttons, i want the same actions for the tab clicks. any idea?

Comment: Can you create A fiddle for that?